# Eclipse Java Remote Debug: How do I ensure that the code I've got in my project is the same as the code running in the JVM?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, remote-debugging

I've got some existing source code, and jars for a webapp. I am attempting to run the webabb using tomcat and then remote debugging the tomcat server using eclipse to figure out what is happening with the webapp.

For some reason however, eclipse refuses to trap any breakpoints. I've compared the md5sums of the jars on the server with the ones I've got in my debug project, and they match.

Is there some way I can ask eclipse to reconcile the java classes in the remote JVM with the java classes in the local jars and make sure they correspond. Or, perhaps, more specifically, whether the code associated with breakpoints I've set have actually be loaded into the remote JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that on the Java Compiler properties page for the java projects in question that the class file options are all checked (you only need the first three but having all five checked is a good thing for debugging)